How to export custom post type posts based on date range
Is it possible, either through code, or wp-admin settings, or the database, to be able to download posts from a custom post type, based on a specific date range?
When I go into wp-admin and use the export tool, I can easily download posts based on a given date range like so...

But the moment, I select my "Careers" custom post type, there is no Start date or End date option.
Can we set this up today within modern WordPress to export based on date range?

If you have access to WP CLI, may be worth trying the wp export command.
wp export --post_type=career --start_date=2011-01-01 --end_date=2011-12-31

